# MySQL find and replace a string with variable content

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress, string, sql-update

For some reasons, I uninstalled VC Bakery plugin on WordPress, but i have like 6000 posts using VC short codes, I'm trying to replace those shortcodes with something else. For e.g.

What SQL query can I use to turn this content:

```
[vc_row][vc_column][vc_single_image image="48526" img_size="full"][/vc_column][/vc_row]
```

To:

```
<img src="somethinghere" alt=""/>
```

Applying changes to table "wp_posts", column "post_content".

Any solution ? thanks :)

Comment: Just use `replace()`? What is the problem?

Comment: I have 6000 records, each with different image number, I can't do it 1 by 1, trying to replace it all in 1 query run

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use string function `replace()`?

```
uppdate wp_posts
set post_content = replace(
    post_content,
    '[vc_row][vc_column][vc_single_image image="48526" img_size="full"][/vc_column][/vc_row]',
    '<img src="somethinghere" alt=""/>'
)
where post_content like '%[vc_row][vc_column][vc_single_image image="48526" img_size="full"][/vc_column][/vc_row]%'
```

Comment: I have 6000 records, each record have different image number, the example i provided have image number 48526. I'm trying to run a query to change all records at once.